# Function inside a function for scoping

Tags: javascript

I am confused about this code how is this working although it looks simple but i am not getting the point of its working

```
<script>
function makeAdder(x) {
 return function(y) {
 return x + y;
 };
}
var add5 = makeAdder(5);
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

console.log(add5(2)); 
console.log(add10(2)); 
</script>
```

Comment: "I am confused" isn't really an answerable question.  Start by formatting your code for readability (indentation is important).  From there, what behavior are you observing from this code?  What behavior were you expecting?  Why?

Comment: I am asking just for the working of this code that how it works ?

Comment: can you please help me to know the working of this code i am just stuck up at this

Comment: I suggest to read about "closures" (function objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand how closure works in JavaScript, then you will be able to understand.

Closure can simply be defined as "In JavaScript, the inner function has the access to all the variables defined outside of that functions."

Try understanding the concepts before trying to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

the function makeAdder returns a function that already will have "x" set with what ever you passed into "makeAdder"

```
<script>
function makeAdder(x) {
    return function(y) {
        return x + y;
    };
}
var add5 = makeAdder(5);
//at this point "add5" looks like this:
/*
function add5(y){
    return 5 + y;
}

so if we do: add5(2) - we know why we see the result we do
*/

console.log(add5(2)); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called `Closure`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

If you refer a variable in a function, it first checks that variable in its scope (inside that function) and if not found, it looks into that the environment where is was defined/declared.

So when you call your outer function with some parameter, it returns a new function. Inner function on invocation return sum of `x` a variable in parent scope when it (function) was defined and `y` the parameter passed to innner function. So inner function will keep remember the value of x when it was defined.

e.g.

```
var add5 = makeAdder(5);
```

Now `add5` is a funtion which when initialized, value of x in it's parent scope was `5`, so whenever you will call `add5(4)`, it will do `x + y` where `x = 5` value when retruned function was defined and `y = 4` the value passed to `add5` function or returned function.

I hope that will explain but I would suggest to read more about `Javascript Closures`. I added one reference above.

Comment: you said that when i call my outer function with some parameter it returns a new function what does it exactly mean?

Comment: can u please elaborate